# Resources$NotFoundException when calling Robolectric.buildActivity()

Tags: java, android, unit-testing, junit4, robolectric

I am using Robolectric 3.0 RC3 for unit testing in Android Studio. And I am getting a `ResourceNotFoundException` every time I run the test. Please help me resolve the issue.

**build.gradle**

```
dependencies {
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.0.0'
    testCompile 'org.mockito:mockito-core:1.9.5'
    testCompile 'org.robolectric:robolectric:3.0-rc3'
    compile 'com.ibm.icu:icu4j:53.1'
}
```

**Test Class**

```
@Before
public void setUp() throws Exception {
    activity = Robolectric.buildActivity(MainActivity.class).create().get();
}
@Test
public void pressingTheButtonShouldStartTheListActivity() throws Exception {
   //Something to test
}
```

So, whenever `Robolectric.buildActivity()` I get the `Resources$NotFoundException`. Resource `#0x7f040016` points to `R.layout.activity_main`(xml). Following id the stack trace-

```
android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Unable to find resource ID #0x7f040016
at org.robolectric.shadows.ShadowResources.checkResName(ShadowResources.java:343)
at org.robolectric.shadows.ShadowResources.resolveResName(ShadowResources.java:338)
at org.robolectric.shadows.ShadowResources.loadXmlResourceParser(ShadowResources.java:429)
at android.content.res.Resources.loadXmlResourceParser(Resources.java)
at android.content.res.Resources.getLayout(Resources.java:852)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:394)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:352)
at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:256)
at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1867)
at com.aricent.anas.unittesting2.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:15) //****HERE****
at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5008)
at org.robolectric.util.ReflectionHelpers.callInstanceMethod(ReflectionHelpers.java:195)
at org.robolectric.util.ActivityController$1.run(ActivityController.java:122)
at org.robolectric.shadows.ShadowLooper.runPaused(ShadowLooper.java:305)
at org.robolectric.shadows.CoreShadowsAdapter$2.runPaused(CoreShadowsAdapter.java:45)
at org.robolectric.util.ActivityController.create(ActivityController.java:118)
at org.robolectric.util.ActivityController.create(ActivityController.java:129)
at com.aricent.anas.unittesting2.MainActivityTest.setUp(MainActivityTest.java:32) //****HERE****
at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:50)
at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:24)
at org.robolectric.RobolectricTestRunner$2.evaluate(RobolectricTestRunner.java:245)
at org.robolectric.RobolectricTestRunner.runChild(RobolectricTestRunner.java:185)
at org.robolectric.RobolectricTestRunner.runChild(RobolectricTestRunner.java:54)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
at org.robolectric.RobolectricTestRunner$1.evaluate(RobolectricTestRunner.java:149)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:137)
at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:140)


Process finished with exit code -1
```

**MainActivity.java:15** is `setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);`

**MainActivityTest.java:32** is `activity = Robolectric.buildActivity(MainActivity.class).create().get();`

Comment: What is working directory in your test run configuration?

Comment: @EugenMartynov $MODULE_DIR$

Comment: Do you have some custom views in Activity?

Comment: @EugenMartynov: Just a plain RelativeLayout with a TextView inside.

Comment: @AnasAzeem Use `RobolectricGradleTestRunner`  instead of `RobolectricTestRunner` this should resolve your issue

Comment: I'll test that and will then get back here.

Comment: The solution worked for me is here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/45571884/4802664

Comment: Here is the correct solution: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45922916/robolectric-resourcesnotfoundexception-string-resource-id-with-android-gradle

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is your test class annotated correctly? And is it using the correct path to a manifest file?
The following works for me:

```
@RunWith(RobolectricTestRunner.class)
@Config(manifest = "src/main/AndroidManifest.xml", emulateSdk = Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP)
public class MyActivityTest { .... }
```

Removing the Config annotation causes the ResourcesNotFound exception you mentioned.

Comment: The part `manifest = "src/main/AndroidManifest.xml"` may help help for this issue but it will give you later more and more issues. Instead of `RobolectricTestRunner` use the `RobolectricGradleTestRunner`

Comment: `emulateSdk` is deprecated and removed from Robolectric 3.0, use `sdk`.

Answer (score 0):

This is realy help for me with Robolectric!
Open Gradle, Double click on ProjectName > :app > Tasks > verification > testDebugUnitTest.[image: Like in picture]
More details  [here](https://android.jlelse.eu/robolectric-unit-testing-framework-for-android-b78ebac0b411)