# Robolectric: Resources$NotFoundException: String resource ID with Android Gradle Plugin 3

Tags: android, unit-testing, testing, android-testing, robolectric

```
Android Studio 3.0 Beta2
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.0-beta3'
testCompile 'org.robolectric:robolectric:3.4.2'
```

Test class that I am using that fails to run:

```
@Config(constants = BuildConfig.class, sdk = Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP)
@RunWith(RobolectricTestRunner.class)
public class RecipeAdapterTest {
    private MainActivity activity;

    @Before
    public void setup() {

    activity = Robolectric.setupActivity(MainActivity.class);

    /* Also tried this same Error
     activity = Robolectric.buildActivity(MainActivity)
                .create()
                .resume()
                .get();
    */
    }

    @Test
    public void testActivityShouldNotBeNull() {
        assertThat(activity, is(notNullValue()));
    }
}
```

This is the stack trace of the error:

```
android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: String resource ID #0x7f0c0020

    at android.content.res.Resources.getText(Resources.java:274)
    at android.content.res.Resources.getString(Resources.java:360)
    at android.content.Context.getString(Context.java:376)
    at org.robolectric.shadows.ShadowActivity.getActivityTitle(ShadowActivity.java:100)
    at org.robolectric.shadows.ShadowActivity.callAttach(ShadowActivity.java:110)
    at org.robolectric.android.controller.ActivityController.attach(ActivityController.java:56)
    at org.robolectric.android.controller.ActivityController.of(ActivityController.java:25)
    at org.robolectric.Robolectric.buildActivity(Robolectric.java:98)
    at org.robolectric.Robolectric.buildActivity(Robolectric.java:94)
    at org.robolectric.Robolectric.setupActivity(Robolectric.java:102)
    at me.androidbox.busbybaking.adapters.RecipeAdapterTest.setup(RecipeAdapterTest.java:63)
```

In the `Edit Configurations` I have set the `Working Directory` to `$MODULE_DIR$`

Many thanks for any suggestion.

Comment: Do you see same error when you run it from command line and gradle?

Comment: This works if I open the project in Android Studio 2.3.3 and use gradle version 2.3.3 and set jackOptions { enabled true } and  compileOptions { sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8 targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8 }

Comment: `jack` is depricated. If you don't do your modifications in the `build.gradle` file can you run it successfully from the command line?

Comment: I have reverted back to the AS 3.0. I have run the test on the command line `./gradlew test` and I get the same problem as before `NotFoundException`

Comment: Are you using macOS or Windows?

Comment: @sarkar I'm using Linux 26 fedora 26

Comment: https://androidstudio.googleblog.com/2017/06/android-studio-30-canary-5-is-now.html

Comment: I wasn't using Robolectric. It was occurring because I was getting context with `InstrumentationRegistry.getInstrumentation().context`. Once I replaced `.context` with `.targetContext` the exception was gone.

Answer (score 94, accepted):

[As mentioned](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/64107525#comment3) by an engineer from Google team (most possibly [Xavier Ducrohet](https://twitter.com/droidxav)), Robolectric has issues with AAPT2:

> Robolectric is not compatible with aapt2.

Two options here.

First option - follow Robolectric [guidelines for Android Studio 3.0+](http://robolectric.org/getting-started/#building-with-gradle)

> Add the following to your build.gradle:

```
android {
  testOptions {
    unitTests {
      includeAndroidResources = true
    }
  }
}
```

> Annotate your test with the Robolectric test runner:

```
@RunWith(RobolectricTestRunner.class)
public class SandwichTest {
}
```

---

Second option: disable AAPT2 adding following line into `gradle.properties` file:

```
android.enableAapt2=false
```

Comment: Thanks, it looks like `android.enableAapt2=false` does the trick.

Comment: This works, but disabling this option: `android.enableAapt2=false
` caused other errors.
Now we have to add a parameter for string resources. Maybe there is some better solution?

Comment: android.enableAapt2=false is deprecated now

Answer (score 12):

The [Robolectric documentation](http://robolectric.org/getting-started/) states that the following configuration should be used with Android Studio 3.x:

```
android {
  testOptions {
    unitTests.includeAndroidResources true
  }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

*(for anyone that might be looking for a solution to a similar problem)*

---

Be sure to use

```
RuntimeEnvironment.application
```

and **not**:

```
RuntimeEnvironment.systemContext
```

when you're trying to resolve resources "manually".

That's one case in which `Resources$NotFoundException` might show up with `Robolectric`.

Answer (score 4):

Not a direct answer to the question, but if you are testing something that needs a context to query resources against I have found the following to work quite well:

```
ApplicationProvider.getApplicationContext()
```

(or RuntimeEnvironment.application -- but this is deprecated in favor of the above)

Answer (score 2):

If your build fails due to an **`AAPT2`** resource processing issue or you want to use **`Roboelectric`**, you can disable **`AAPT2`** by setting **`android.enableAapt2=false`** in your **`gradle.properties`** file and restarting the Gradle daemon by running [**`./gradlew --stop`**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35878520/3395198) from the command line.

Official guideline **[Android Studio 3.0 Release](https://androidstudio.googleblog.com/2017/06/android-studio-30-canary-5-is-now.html)**

Answer (score 1):

I was using espresso, and for that you needed to use app resources, not test resources.

So instead of

```
InstrumentationRegistry.getInstrumentation().context.resources.getString("key")
```

I used

```
activityRule.activity.getString("key")
```

Answer (score -2):

In my case the following solved my issue:
"Problem is related to android studio. Go to 'Run' -> 'Edit configurations...' and change 'Working directory' value to
$MODULE_DIR$

Run your tests.

More info here under 'Building with Android Studio'."

reference: https://github.com/robolectric/robolectric/issues/2653

Answer (score -2):

You can also try `@Config(manifest = "<projectFolder>/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml")` in the case that you can not simply include the resources as some projects tests will fail with that included.