# Robolectric test case for Kotlin code

Tags: java, android, robolectric

I have a MainActivity written in `Kotlin`. I can run the `setupActivity` in `kotlin` like so:

```
@RunWith(RobolectricTestRunner::class)
@Config(constants = BuildConfig::class)
class MyActivityTestKotlin {
    @Before
    public fun setup() {
        Robolectric.setupActivity(MainActivity::class.java)
    }
}
```

However, when I write the test in `java`, I get the error:

`android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: String resource ID #0x7f0c001f`

Java code:

```
@RunWith(RobolectricTestRunner.class)
@Config(constants = BuildConfig.class)
public class MyActivityTest {
    @Before
    public void setup() {
        setupActivity(MainActivity.class);
    }
}
```

Is it possible to write the tests in `java` for such cases?Thanks!!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/45965816/3395198

Answer (score 3):

Add in the gradel unit test option for resource to access compiled resources during testing

```
testOptions {
    unitTests {
        includeAndroidResources = true
    }
}
```

[RoboElectric docs](http://robolectric.org/getting-started/)